# Anchor macro for paths

Tags: macros, metapost

I am trying to build a macro to assign anchors for a given path. This is what I have:

```
beginfig(1);
def anchors(expr p) =
  pair p.n, p.e, p.s, p.w;
  p.n := .5(ulcorner p + urcorner p);
  p.e := .5(urcorner p + lrcorner p);
  p.s := .5(llcorner p + lrcorner p);
  p.w := .5(ulcorner p + llcorner p);
enddef;
path b; b := unitsquare scaled 2cm;
anchors(b);
endfig;
end;
```

But this won't work. However, if I take out the innards of the macro and inline them, everything works dandy. How come?

Comment: You're using `p.n` in the definition, but there `p` means the argument and that's illegal. Is your intention to define `b.n` and so on?

Comment: @egreg: yes; given a path, it should define the anchor points for that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `suffix` and not `expr`:

```
def anchors(suffix p) =
pair p.n, p.e, p.s, p.w;
  p.n := .5(ulcorner p + urcorner p);
  p.e := .5(urcorner p + lrcorner p);
  p.s := .5(llcorner p + lrcorner p);
  p.w := .5(ulcorner p + llcorner p);
enddef;
path b; b := unitsquare scaled 1pt;
anchors(b);
show b.n;
show b.e;
show b.s;
show b.w;
end
```

This outputs

```
>> (0.49814,0.99626)
>> (0.99626,0.49814)
>> (0.49814,0)
>> (0,0.49814)
```